# Finding line duplicates in text file where lines can be identical to each other

Tags: text-processing

I've made a system where the data in the database is filled when the system reads a file. This file may be filled at a later stage, which creates a demand to read the same file again.

The data itself is represented on each line of the file, and the tough part is to find unique values, and I'll tell you why.

The file may look like this:

```
123 20110101 4123 Hello
123 20110101 4123 Hello
124 20110102 6133 Hello again
125 20110103 6425 Yes
```

The real problem here is that the first two lines aren't duplicates, so they're both going to get read into the database by the system.

As I earlier told, this file may be added to at a later stage, making it necessary that we read it again. As I was not familiar with how text was appended to the file, I made the assumption that new data would be appended to the end of the file. Therefore I added file row number to each row in the database, to make lines unique. However, I was wrong...

As it turns out, data where appended to the file in the middle of it as well.

This means we now may have the following file:

```
123 20110101 4123 Hello
123 20110101 4123 Hello
124 20110102 6133 Hello again
123 20110101 4123 Hello
125 20110103 6425 Yes
```

And now we stand before the second time we read the file. In this case I only want to read the fourth line, as this is the only new line. How can I find the new line and get rid of the others?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand: do you want to discover the new lines added to a file? Or only when they're not duplicates of previously added lines?

Comment: I want to discover the new lines. The new lines may contain the same characters as another previously added line, but in that case it's not a duplicate.

Comment: I'm a bit afraid that you are trying to do [IPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) via appending to temporary file. Do you want to just pass lines of text from one program to another? This task can be done in much more efficient and robust ways not involving any files.

Comment: No, I'm bound to use the text files.

Comment: If this is going into a database, I cannot fathom why the database cannot handle recognizing and squashing duplicate data insertions. In any case, you can easily do this in any one of a number of scripting languages which have hash tables and such. Simply read the file line by line, stick the lines into a hash table, but first checking whether the line already occurs. If it's the first occurrence, report the line, and do not report subsequent occurrences. Of course, you need an amount of hash storage proportional to the number of unique lines in the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save the old version of the file, then run a `diff` on the old version and the new version. That will give you the newly added lines.

Comment: No, they're not necessary after one and another.

Comment: Awesome, will try it out tomorrow! Thank you!